# Setting ServiceStack requests authentication from OpenAuth token

Tags: oauth-2.0, servicestack, dotnetopenauth

(This question can be seen as follow ups to these two StackOverflow posts about OpenAuth with DotNetOpenAuth in a ServiceStack scenario: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257753/how-do-i-authorize-access-to-servicestack-resources-using-oauth2-access-tokens-v) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251508/how-to-build-secured-api-using-servicestack-as-resource-server-with-oauth2-0))

From what I understand, ServiceStack uses an `IAuthSession` to know which user is authenticated, but this seems to rely on the HTTP session cookie. With OAuth request, no such cookie exist.

**Question:** I want my ServiceStack requests to be considered authenticated if 1) a the browser cookie is present or 2) if the OAuth Authentication Header *Bearer* is present. How should I do this?

I tried the following to set the thread's authentication, but it relies on ASP.NET's `HttpContext.Current.User`.

I'd also like it to work on both IIS hosted and Self-Hosted scenarios...

```
var analyzer = new StandardAccessTokenAnalyzer((RSACryptoServiceProvider)signCert.PublicKey.Key, (RSACryptoServiceProvider)encryptCert.PrivateKey);
var resourceServer = new ResourceServer(analyzer);
var requestWrapper = new HttpRequestWrapper((HttpRequest)request.OriginalRequest);

var principal = resourceServer.GetPrincipal(requestWrapper, requiredScopes);
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you creating your custom oAuthProvider by extending out of the box provider? https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/OpenId#creating-a-custom-openid-provider - where is the code written?

Comment: No, I created a custom method attribute (`RequireOAuth2ScopeAttribute`) as suggested in the referenced SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18323086/918244

Comment: Also, from what I understand (I could be wrong), OAuthProvider classes are the actual openauth clients to use OAuth to login a user (e.g Twitter login, Facebook, etc.) In my case, ServiceStack *IS* the OAuth Provider, some other system is the client.